# apache + php configuration on mac

Tags: php, macos, apache

Good day.
I have a problem with Apache configuring on my Mac.
I installed apache and php from MacPorts, apache works fine.
When I add line

```
Include conf/extra/mod_php.conf
```

and restart apache - here is an error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 119 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /opt/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/opt/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib\n  Referenced from: /opt/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so\n  Reason: Incompatible library version: libphp5.so requires version 6.0.0 or later, but libaprutil-1.0.dylib provides version 4.0.0
```

So, this is my question: what should I do for resolve this problem?
thanks a lot!
Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditch MacPort and install [**MAMP from this link**.](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html)

MAMP installer comes with Apache, PHP and MySQL bundled.

**Update:** There is a better LAMP package available now on OSX called [AMPPS](http://ampps.com/).